# R: can I do the following using Reduce (or another high-level function)?

Tags: r, functional-programming

I have a function which takes as inputs a data frame and additional arguments which determine some type of change to the data frame. As a simple example:

```
col_with_ones <- function(df, col_name) {
  df[[col_name]] <- 1
  df
}
```

Is there a way I can use `Reduce` (or any other 'high-level' function) to apply multiple changes to a dataframe? e.g. continuing the example above, could I use `Reduce` to do the following:

```
df <- data.frame(a = runif(10))
for (letter in letters[2:5]) {
  df <- col_with_ones(df, letter)
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quite simply:

```
Reduce(col_with_ones, letters[2:5], init = df)
```

Comment: perfect! this is exactly what i was hoping for.